# Extracting information from an array in php

Tags: php, arrays, parsing, web

Can any one tell me how to extract the 'honda' value out of the array below using php?

```
{
        "version": "1.0",
        "encoding": "UTF-8",
        "entry": {
            "name": "bob",
            "car": {
                "model": "honda"
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Convert to xml file type.

Comment: [P.S. `json_decode()`.](http://codepad.viper-7.com/CAQNbx)

Comment: $myarray['entry']['car']['model'] maybe =)

Comment: It looks like it's JSON.

Comment: @user1929959 wut? Where's the xml?

Comment: @PeeHaa He forget a few steps: Convert to XML, send a web request, compile it with Ruby and then print the binary code

Comment: @DanLee You just made my day :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a json encoded object. What you could do is:

```
$info = json_decode($data, true); //where $data has your stuff from the question
$carModel = $obj['entry']['car']['model'];
```

Comment: when I try $arr = json_decode($obj); echo $arr['entry']; all I get is a single curly brace i.e. "{"

Comment: sorry, you need `json_decode($data, true);`. I updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

If you have all that in a variable called "obj", then

```
$obj = '{ "version": "1.0", "encoding": "UTF-8", "entry": { "name": "bob", "car": { "model": "honda" } } }';     
$arr = json_decode($obj, true);
echo $arr['entry']['car']['model'];
```

should be 'honda'

EDITED: Per Omar below, you do need the true as the second param in json_decode. He should get selected as the correct answer.

Comment: when I try $arr = json_decode($obj); echo $arr['entry']; all I get is a single curly brace i.e. "{"

Comment: is it all in a string? like: $obj = '{
        "version": "1.0",
        "encoding": "UTF-8",
        "entry": {
            "name": "bob",
            "car": {
                "model": "honda"
            }
        }
    }';

Comment: Actually, select Omar as the correct answer, you need that "true" param.

Answer (score 0):

Use json_decode as: http://php.net/manual/fr/function.json-decode.php

> `<?php`
>
> `$json = '{"version": "1.0","encoding": "UTF-8","entry": {"name": "bob","car": {"model": "honda"} } }';`
>
> `$tab   = json_decode($json, true);`
>
> `$honda = $tab['entry']['car']['model'];`
>
> `var_dump($honda);`
>
> > `// or with object:`
>
> `$obj   = json_decode($json);`
>
> `$honda = $obj->entry->car->model;`
>
> `var_dump($honda);`